# Programmatically Create Checkbox Column inside a Gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I often use this code to create template fields for buttons, checkboxes, labels etc. inside a gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data_1" ShowHeader="False" Visible="True">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' 
  CommandName="Button1_Command" CssClass="round_button" 
  Height="20px" Width="20px" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

But this time, the number of columns with checkbox are uncertain. (I need to pull a certain data in the database to determine how many checkbox columns I would need). How do I programmatically create a checkbox column upon page load?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the below codes help you. It's not a complete code but it would give you hint or idea on how to create checkbox column programmaticaly. Thanks.

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdView">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Button" ShowHeader="False" Visible="True">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
                        CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'
                        CommandName="Button1_Command" CssClass="round_button"
                        Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Public Class GridViewCustomColumn
        Public Property ColumnName As Boolean
        Public Property HeaderName As String
    End Class

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim lists As New List(Of GridViewCustomColumn) From { _
            New GridViewCustomColumn() With {.ColumnName = False, .HeaderName = "TestHeaderName1"}, _
            New GridViewCustomColumn() With {.ColumnName = True, .HeaderName = "TestHeaderName2"}}

        grdView.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        Dim templateField As New TemplateField()
        templateField.ItemTemplate = New CheckBoxTemplateImpl("ColumnName")
        grdView.Columns.Add(templateField)
        grdView.DataSource = lists
        grdView.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Public Class CheckBoxTemplateImpl
        Implements ITemplate

        Public Property ColumnName As String
        Public Sub New(columnName As String)
            Me.ColumnName = columnName
        End Sub

        Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
            Dim chkBox As New CheckBox()
            AddHandler chkBox.DataBinding, AddressOf chkBox_DataBinding
            container.Controls.Add(chkBox)
        End Sub

        Private Sub chkBox_DataBinding(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
            Dim chkBox As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
            Dim gridViewRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(chkBox.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
            Dim bindValue As Object = DataBinder.Eval(gridViewRow.DataItem, ColumnName)
            If bindValue IsNot Nothing Then
                chkBox.Text = bindValue.ToString()
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: oh. okay. I get it. I will try it now. Thank you!